# Angular 4 - ngFor for stream

Tags: angular

this is my example:

**my-list.component.ts:**

```
export class MyList implements OnInit {
  values: Observable<number>;
  ngOnInit(){
   this.values= Observable
    .from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    .map(function (value) { return Observable.of(value).delay(2000); })
    .concatAll();
//    this.values.subscribe(x => console.log(x)); this is OK
  }
}
```

**my-list.component.html:**

```
<div *ngFor="let v of values|async">
  {{v}}
</div>
```

But i received error:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '1' of type 'number'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

I thought I can create ngFor with "stream". It is way how to do it? Of course, I could somethink like this:

```
.subscribe(x => this.data.push(x))
*ngFor="let v of values"
```

I don't understand how to use async pipe. Thanks

Comment: `console.log(values)` and show output

Comment: @bluray, when you make `variable=Observable(...)` you're equaling "variable" to the **observable** not to the result. You need write this.value=x INTO the subscribe function

Comment: *ngFor here received a number - 1 - as argument. naturally, it is not iterable. what's your use case? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I would like to display values when they received. First it will be displayed 1, after two seconds 1,2 after two seconds 1,2,3...

Comment: I thought that it was doing async pipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular 8 answer - should translate to Angular 4

### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2tdcob)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of, from, interval} from 'rxjs'
import { map, delay, tap, scan, skip, takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let v of values$|async">
      {{v}}
    </div>
  `

})
export class AppComponent  {
  values$: Observable<number[]>;
  ngOnInit(){

    // streams
    const counter$ = interval(1000)

    this.values$ = counter$.pipe(
      skip(1),
      scan((acc, cur) => {
        return [ ...acc, cur]
      }, []),
      takeWhile(arr => arr.length < 20) // <--- some end condition
    )
  }
}
```

---

There's nothing special about the async pipe, it takes an Observable and subscribes for you in the template and unsubscribes for you on component destruction. Keep to the convention of using a $ on the end of observable streams variables.

The following

```
<div *ngFor="let v of values$ | async">
  {{v}}
</div>
```

is equivalent to

```
<div *ngFor="let v of values">
  {{v}}
</div>
```

where in your ts file you do this

```
values$.subscribe(values => this.values = values)
```

Answer (score 0):

`concatAll` does not concat results to array. it rather makes your observables(delayed numbers) chain one after another completes. I think what you are trying to achieve is

```
  this.values= Observable
    .from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    .map(function (value) { return Observable.of(value).delay(2000); })
    .concatAll()
//    .subscribe(x => console.log(x)); here this would emit 1 then 2 then 3 ...
    .scan((array, nextValue) => array.concat(nextValue), [])
//    .subscribe(x => console.log(x)); here this would emit [1] then [1,2] then [1,2,3]...
```

with this `scan` you will get the aggregated array every time new events comes

Answer (score 0):

you could use .scan() operator

```
this.values= Observable
    .from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    .map(function (value) { return Observable.of(value).delay(2000); })
    .concatAll().
    .scan((acc, value) => [...acc, value], []);
```

it acts pretty much like .reduce on array. (rx .reduce() operator would do the same, but emits only when the observable completes)